# How to schedule concurrent Runnables according to number of threads whereas a thread has to wait a delay after completing the task

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, threadpoolexecutor

I am scheduling tasks with a specific delay to process my items:

```
while (currentPosition < count) {
    ExtractItemsProcessor extractItemsProcessor = 
        getExtractItemsProcessor(currentPosition, currentPositionLogger);
    executor.schedule(extractItemsProcessor, waitBetweenProzesses, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    waitBetweenProzesses += sleepTime;
    currentPosition += chunkSize;
}
```

How can i schedule for example 3 tasks (having an executor with 3 threads) and each thread has to wait for 10 seconds after it finished its task?

Comment: If I'm being honest Eric, why do you need 3 threads if you're making them wait 10 seconds per task anyway? It seems highly inefficient. Regardless, if you want to do this look into the Sleep() method

Comment: yes thats true, sleep would kind of solve my problem, but i was looking for something similar like .scheduleWithFixedDelay but for different tasks and not the same one being executed periodically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREADS)* which returns an ExecutorService. Then with this executorService you can *submit* a task. Example :

```
private static final int NB_THREADS = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREADS);

    for (int i = 0; i < NB_THREADS; i++) {
        final int nb = i + 1;
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Task " + nb);
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                    System.out.println("Task " + nb + " terminated");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    System.out.println("Error during thread await " + e); // Logging framework should be here
                }
            }
        };

        executorService.submit(task);
    }


    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println("Error during thread await " + e);
    }
}
```

It will run te 3 tasks in parallel and output looks like this :

```
Task 1
Task 3
Task 2
Task1 terminated
Task2 terminated
Task3 terminated
```

In your case you could do something like :

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NB_THREADS);
while (currentPosition < count) {
    ExtractItemsProcessor extractItemsProcessor =
            getExtractItemsProcessor(currentPosition, currentPositionLogger);
    executorService.submit(extractItemsProcessor); // In processor you should add the sleep method
    waitBetweenProzesses += sleepTime;
    currentPosition += chunkSize;
}
```